# TPL Dataflow BufferBlock<> consumer works in main-thread in WPF

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have a simple producer-consumer class using a `BufferBlock` object to post messages adapted from [TPL Dataflow Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) and my problem is that using it in a WPF app causes that the consumer receives data in the same main-thread while the console application executes it in a worker thread. Here is my code:

```
public class DataflowProducerConsumer
{
    BufferBlock<int> _buffer;

    public DataflowProducerConsumer()
    {
        _buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();

        var consumer = UseBufferBlock(_buffer);
    }

    public void Produce(int number)
    {
        _buffer.Post(number);

        var actionBlock = UseActionBlock();
        actionBlock.Post(number);
    }

    public async Task UseBufferBlock(ISourceBlock<int> source)
    {
        while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            int data = source.Receive();

            // ...process data asyncron
            Console.WriteLine("BufferBlock-Thread {0} received: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, data);
        }
    }

    public ITargetBlock<int> UseActionBlock()
    {
        return new ActionBlock<int>(data =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ActionBlock-Thread: {0} received: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, data));
        });
    }
}
```

Test executed in main or on Click-event:

```
var obj = new DataflowProducerConsumer();
obj.Produce(19);
```

Well, I changed `Post` to `SendAsync` without success. And the `ActionBlock` part works well. What's the difference? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just link the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not related to TPL DataFlow itself, but rather to the following statement:

```
await source.OutputAvailableAsync()
```

await will capture current `SynchronizationContext` and post continuation (the rest of the method after await) to it. If there is no synchronization context (like in console app) - it will post continuation to thread pool thread.

WPF has synchronization context, and posting to it is posting to UI thread (like `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`), so that's what you observe.

To prevent capturing current synchronization context (and so - to always post continuation to thread pool thread), use `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    int data = source.Receive();

    // ...process data asyncron
    Console.WriteLine("BufferBlock-Thread {0} received: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, data);
}
```

Also note that there is `ReceiveAsync()` method, which you can use (and await) instead of synchronous `Receive()`, though that is not related to the problem in question.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks. I need to read more about synchronization context, I think ;-)

Comment: @alex555 here is a good source right from one of the authors of this feature: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/